# Detecting OS version in Javascript and redirecting

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect, mobile

Good Day

I have done some research and found that you can use the following javascript to detect a users OS, whether it is Android, iOS, Windows etc:

```
var OSName="Unknown OS";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win")!=-1) OSName="Windows";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac")!=-1) OSName="MacOS";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("X11")!=-1) OSName="UNIX";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Linux")!=-1) OSName="Linux";

document.write('Your OS: '+OSName);
```

Now what I would like to do is to relocate a user, based on his OS, to either the apple Appstore or google Play Store like this:

HTML:

```
<a href="" id="redirect">Download our App</a>
```

and the associated JS

```
if (OSName="MacOS" ){
$("#redirect").attr("href", "http://www.itunes.com/myapp")
}

elseif (OSName="Linux"){
$("#redirect").attr("href", "http://www.play.google.com/")
}
  (Linux is for Android right? )
```

Is this the right/best way of doing it/ Will my code work?

Thank you

Comment: you also need a space after the else

Comment: ok thanks...picked that up when the code did not work...thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code can be simplified:

```
var playStoreUrl = "http://www.play.google.com/",
    appStoreUrl  = "http://www.itunes.com/myapp",
    platform     = navigator.platform;

if (/mac/i.test(platform))
    $("#redirect").attr("href", appStoreUrl);
else if (/linux/i.test(platform))
    $("#redirect").attr("href", playStoreUrl);
else
    // Handle the case where the OS is neither MacOS nor Linux
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes it'll work.. You can also use this library.

[Detect Mobile Browsers JS](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/)

Comment: Is checking for the browser instead of the OS reliable?

Comment: well, if the script you have mentioned in the question is sufficient for getting your work done, go ahead with it :)

Answer (score 1):

```
return {
     isMac105: /Mac OS X 10_5/.test(userAgent),
     isMac106: /Mac OS X 10_6/.test(userAgent),
     isMac107: /Mac OS X 10_7/.test(userAgent),
     isMac108: /Mac OS X 10_8/.test(userAgent),
 };
```

useragent for mac e.g.

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_1) AppleWebKit/536.25 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Safari/536.25

Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_5_8; ru) AppleWebKit/533.18.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2 Safari/533.18.5
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but not sure where/how to implement this? I'm still learning JS