# How do you redirect an iPhone to iTunes?

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, redirect

When opening http://example.com/app I want all iPhones to open the app in iTunes.

right the html header has

```
    <meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=XXX" >
```

which renders a bar prompting for install

further this JS from another [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14931598/detecting-os-version-in-javascript-and-redirecting)

```
var platform  = navigator.platform;
        if (/mac/i.test(platform))
            window.location = iuntes_url;
        else if (/linux/i.test(platform))
            window.location = play_url;
```

works for android, but not for iPhone.

This link however http://authy.com/install does open in iTunes on an iPhone can't find out this is done?

how can I open the app store for an iOS user when they go to example.com/app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the fact I was using the variable  `window.location` which on devices should just be `location`

```
var platform  = navigator.platform;
    if (/mac/i.test(platform))
        location = iuntes_url;
    else if (/linux/i.test(platform))
        location = play_url;
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the URL you are sending them to? It should lead with itms-apps:// not http://

Comment: thanks, I just solved this by removing `window.` from the code, it works now, with http